# rtl_test fails because of udev (i think) on a raspberry pi 4

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, realtek, udev

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 Raspberry Pi 4
The question is that how do I make it not out put that error.
Note, I did summit a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rtl-sdr/+bug/1978148)

rtl_test output

```
Found 1 device(s):
  0:  , �bߧ��, SN: @�ާ��

Using device 0: Generic RTL2832U OEM
usb_open error -3
Please fix the device permissions, e.g. by installing the udev rules file rtl-sdr.rules
Failed to open rtlsdr device #0.
```

`lsusb` output

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:2838 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL2838 DVB-T
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Yes the formatting is pore so please edit it or ask

Comment: Give this a try https://github.com/osmocom/rtl-sdr/blob/master/rtl-sdr.rules

Comment: @nobody the same file was in this package https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/librtlsdr0/filelist and the package is installed

Comment: If I run `rtl_test` with sudo it works cool

Comment: but gqrx does not work so ya

Comment: i'm sitting for the wrong system. Is your user in group plugdev?

Comment: @nobody yep works add that as a answer

Comment: I make it tomorrow, good that it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have only access with grandet rights (sudo) to an device you can grep recursive in udev rules.d for your device (device-id or vendor-id).
Here

```
grep -r 2838 /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-librtlsdr0.rules:SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bda", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2838", ENV{ID_SOFTWARE_RADIO}="1", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

the device "belongs" to group plugdev here. So your user has to be in group plugdev (here).

Sorry not good in explaining in english.